# github-actions on: schedule creating multiple runs

Tags: scheduled-tasks, github-actions

i have a github scheduled for every saturday that has two jobs. One reads a file and pipes it's json content to be used in a matrix workflow. Using the workflow dispatch it works just fine [print-screen of working run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRoFG.png) but every monday i come to a couple hundred workflow runs... any idea what i am doing wrong?

```
name: .OWASP FULL SCAN
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '* * * * SAT'

jobs:
  matrix_job:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, Linux, saas]
    outputs:
      matrix_out: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix_out }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - id: set-matrix
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=matrix_out::$(cat images_full.json)"
  call_dependency_scan:
    needs: matrix_job
    uses: hv-actions/dependency-check/.github/workflows/matrix.yml@MLAAS
    with:
      IMAGE_NAMES: ${{ needs.matrix_job.outputs.matrix_out }}
      REGISTRY_URL: "***.azurecr.io"
    secrets:
      CODE_DX_SERVER_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.*** }}
      CODE_DX_SERVER_URL: ${{ secrets.*** }}
      CODE_DX_SERVER_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.*** }}
      REGISTRY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.*** }}
      REGISTRY_USER: ${{ secrets.*** }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cron schedule is in fact running [every minute on a Saturday](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_SAT). You should instead set it as a fixed time on Saturday, like 03:00: `0 3 * * SAT`.

Comment: ty, should work, my bad